# Show/Hide button in listview android,

Tags: android, listview, button, hide, show

Can anyone knows how can i make something like this in ListView ?

When a item in ListView is Clicked the imageButton get Visible.

http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/2377/is4t.png

Then you click another item and the previus item that you clicked get invisible , and the actual item get the image button visible.

http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/1920/lnpy.png

I have searched about this , but i haven't found something to work exactly i want. And i have tried to make the button visible onItemClick for that view , but , when i click another button , the previus item still visible. I have tried to do notifyDataBaseChanged but still there. Thanks for help , and sorry for my bad english.

¿How can i get access on the previous Item View to set button to View.GONE ? 
Code :

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            MPlayer.playSong(position);
            Button bPlaying = (Buttton)view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            bPlaying.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ca.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Comment: You already have almost working solution. All that you need is to hide another icon. You should rather post a code that you tried and ask a specific question.

Comment: Yeah, but que question is how can i get access on the previous View to hide the that button ?

Comment: You might need to incorporate another variable which represents the last view that you added the icon to.

Comment: post your custom adapter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not the best solution but hope this might help you solving you the problem

```
private Button previousButton = null;    
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long arg3) {
        MPlayer.playSong(position);
        if(previousButton != null){
            previousButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        Button bPlaying = (Buttton)view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        bPlaying.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        previousButton = bPlaying;
        ca.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```